# Nattable: Need help to paste data from extenal source to Nattable

Tags: nattable

I am able to implement Copy Paste function for nattable and it is working perfectly inside the nattable and also for other internal nattable.But not able to paste Data for External system.I have tried to extend Copyhandler and Paste handler.But i am not able to get Data from System clipboard.Please help me.

Comment: Depends on what kind of data is on the system clipboard. Hard to help without further information.

Comment: I am copying Data from Excel and try to paste it in Nattable.... I know in nattable we are using Internal Clipboard....We are able to copy data to system clipboard but is there any getter which can be used to get data from System clipboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data from the system clipboard when previously copied data from Excel, you can try to use the following code:

```
    final Clipboard cb = new Clipboard(Display.getCurrent());

    Button paste = new Button(buttonPanel, SWT.PUSH);
    paste.setText("Paste");
    paste.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            TextTransfer transfer = TextTransfer.getInstance();
            String data = (String) cb.getContents(transfer);
            if (data != null) {
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        }
    });
```

You only need to get the data from the system clipboard and interprete it to match your NatTable structure. And you need to be aware that Excel adds new line characters and tabs as delimiter, so you are able to parse the data correctly.

Comment: Thanks Dirk.... I am able to make workbook using Nattable which is working as Excel... Thanks for your help for all the question.....

Comment: It if is working then please accept the answer to indicate that also for others searching for the same answer.